# Information system

Tags: php, asp.net

I want to use php for building an "Information system". The system will consist of

1. Main office
2. Branch office

The Branch office will connect to Main office through a private circuit.

I want to build an information system for communication between the offices. This is a system for communication between banks for client operation with a terminal (get, count, etc)

I don't know whether to use a thin or thick client. For a thin client I should use PHP or ASP.NET.  What do you think? What technologies are best for this purpose?

Comment: What kind of information system? What kind of information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with PHP/Ajax and good database design.

Sure, this depends on the tools you or your company is using on day-to-day basis and the software/technologies you already own.